# ipad2 framebuffer initialized to retina size

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es, framebuffer

I'm using a iPhone/ipad app with an empty view set to use my EAGLView class.
I initialize the framebuffer with:

```
self.contentScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
self.layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]; //this is 1.0
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &defaultFramebuffer);
    glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, defaultFramebuffer);
    glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &colorRenderbuffer);
    glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, colorRenderbuffer);
    [context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];

    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &framebufferWidth);
    glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &framebufferHeight);
```

after that, framebufferWidth is 1568 and framebufferHeight is 1216.
My device is reported by [[UIDevice currentDevice] model] as @"ipad", iOS 4.3.5. Xcode 4.5.1, SDK 6, deployment target 4.3.

Anyone has any idea why I got this sizes and not the 1024x768 ?

Thanks.

Later Edit: same code worked perfectly with Xcode 3.x and SDK 4.3, with deployment target 4.0.

Comment: Maybe you have a better iPad than you thought?  ;-)

Comment: well ... I wish, but I got it when ipad3 was not yet on the market, and when I draw an image full screen, I see just a corner of it like the screen is smaller than the framebuffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1568x1216 must be the size of your `EAGLView` — are you loading it from a NIB or creating it programmatically. Assuming the former, what size is it in there and how are your springs and struts set up? I'll wager than if you log the view's frame you'll see those numbers.

Under iOS 5 or newer you should probably just use `GLKView` rather than rolling your own; is 4.3 deployment still that important to you?

Comment: Indeed, I load it from a nib with the size of iphone's resolution. I'll check the springs and struts and do some debugging and I'll get back with more info, thanks.

Comment: I've done some checks and debugging (it's still not working :-( ), so, the springs and struts are set on all margins for both the window and the EAGLView, also, the autoresize is set on both axes for EAGLView, and it's not available for window.

The sizes are 
-320x460 in initWithCoder of EAGLView
-768x1024 in awakeFromNib (if I create the frame buffer here, I'll get an error 1282 on 'code'[context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)self.layer];'code')
-then layoutSubviews is called and after that the size of the layer is 1216x1568

Any new ideas on this one ?

Answer (score 1):

One solution that I found is to put some code in layoutSubviews of my EAGLView object:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
```

{
    // The framebuffer will be re-created at the beginning of the next setFramebuffer method call.
    [self deleteFramebuffer];

```
CGRect  rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
self.layer.frame = rect;
self.frame = rect;
```

}

Now it works correctly, still I get one openGL error 1282 while calling:

```
glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RGBA8_OES, framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight);
```

I'm still investigating this error, any ideas ?
Thanks,